# Vs2010 MvcBuildViews Not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

This project in Vs2008 targeting .net 3.5 used to compile views.

Vs2010 Targeting .net 4.0 the following view code is not picked up as an error, and  I have not found anyway to listen to the mvcBuildview trace/debug output:

```
<%{ %>
```

A completely unmatched code block declaration is not being picked up, neither was a partial view inheriting from a non existent namespace/class.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugWithBuildViews|AnyCPU' ">

<!--<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>bin/intermediate</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>-->
<!--<MvcBuildViews Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugWithBuildViews' ">true</MvcBuildViews>-->
<EnableUpdateable>false</EnableUpdateable>
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>true</CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>
<CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>GlobalSuppressions.cs</CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

My BeforeBuild:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<WriteLinesToFile File="$(OutputPath)\env.config" Lines="$(Configuration)" Overwrite="true">
</WriteLinesToFile>
```

My AfterBuild:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
<!--<BaseIntermediateOutputPath>[SomeKnownLocationIHaveAccessTo]</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>-->
<Message Importance="high" Text="Precompiling views" />
  <!--<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)..\$(ProjectName)" />-->
<!--<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" />-->
<!--PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)\..\$(ProjectName)"-->
```

I know the `MvcBuildViews` property is true because the `Precompiling views` message comes through. The compile is a success but it does not catch the view compilation errors.

I have Vs2010 ultimate, vs 2008 developer+database edition on this machine.

So either it compiles ignoring the errors with some combinations of the fixes I've tried, or it errors with

`Error  410 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. web.config   100`

The commented out sections are things I have tried
Previously I have tried the fixes from these posts:

- [Compile Views in Asp.net Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [AllowDefinitionMachinetoApplicationError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566215/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-error-when-publishing-from-vs2010-but-on)
- [MvcBuildviews Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100139/trying-to-build-my-net-3-5-mvc-app-in-vs2010-beta2-throws-a-mvcbuildview-error)
- [Turning on MVC Build Views in 2010 TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimlamb/turn-on-compile-time-view-checking-for-asp-net-mvc-projects-in-tfs-build-2010)
- [Johnny Coder](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2010/03/26/uncovering-compiler-errors-in-asp-net-mvc-views/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725387/mvcbuildviews-not-working-correctly

Comment: @Maslow: Did you ever get an answer on this? I've got the same problem and can't get any resolution at all.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank pretty sure I didn't

Comment: @Maslow: Sigh. Such a simple and necessary feature and I can't get it to work no matter what I do!

Answer (score 2):

> Error 410 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. web.config 100

Cleaning the project often helps against this error.