# Can Razor views be compiled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, compilation, razor

I was wondering if Razor views could be compiled, like WebForm based views?

Does it even make sense to compile Razor views and why would somebody want to do that?

Comment: Technically speaking, they are compiled from the just in time compiler. You can also enable building of views to fail the build with a check box.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Please refer this link it may help https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169354/Pre-compiled-Razor-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can. Take a look at the following post: [Compile your asp.net mvc Razor views into a seperate dll](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/)

It's a "step-by-step" guide on how to compile your razor views into a separate dll. I don't know if that's what you aim to do but it'll definitely get you in the right direction.

Comment: This answer is now outdated, you should now refer to this post: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html

Answer (score 59):

> **Edit:**
>
> Here is a blog post on this topic as well:
>
> [How to Detect Errors of Our ASP.NET MVC Views on Compile Time](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-to-detect-errors-of-our-asp-net-mvc-views-on-compile-time-blow-up-in-my-face-theory)

To make your views to be compiled, do the following;

1. Unload your project by right
   clicking the project on the solution
   explorer in VS and clicking unload
   project
2. right click the project which has
   been converted to unavailable
   project and click "Edit
   your_project_name.csproj" (that
   would be .vbproj if your
   project is VB project)
3. see the following code;

   ```
   <!--There some lines of code here and I deleted them to get to the point quickly-->

   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
   ```
4. change the MvcBuildViews tag value from `false` to `true`
5. after that save it and reload your
   project.

after you build your solution to compile it, you will see that your view will be compiled too.

**NOTE:** to test it, break some code in one of your view on purpose and try to build. you will see that you'll get an error message.

Comment: I'll give this a try and see what happens.

Comment: After this change I started getting `"allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level"` error message when building my solution. Solution was to run _Clean Solution_ in *both* debug and release modes.

Comment: i can't see `<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>` in VS2013

Comment: @DotNetDreamer I had the same issue. But I manually added it in, and also used Chris Hynes' answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725387/mvcbuildviews-not-working-correctly).

Comment: In our case, we had to delete the `bin` and `obj` folders to get rid of the error mentioned by @JuhaPalomäki.

Answer (score 34):

The MvcBuildViews check is excellent but it adds a 5-10 second penalty for building your web app if it's complex enough. It doesn't cache the compilation output so it does a full compilation of all your views every time.

I found a nice compromise by following the [above advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515293/430634) and adding a Condition attribute:

```
<MvcBuildViews Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">true</MvcBuildViews>
```

We'd expect ReSharper to flag up any errors in the views anyway and the developer can always build in the release configuration as a test - we have a "preflight" script that developers run so they can easily make sure that package targets work and so on - and if all that fails, the build server will catch it.

Perhaps this trick is obvious but I've only really started learning about msbuild properly as opposed to writing Powershell scripts for these tasks. I hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: That's pure brilliance :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. In fact, the best example I can think of would be email templating engines. If you compile and cache the template, then you can quickly rip off emails without having to go through the parsing all over again.

That's a good example of using Razor outside of MVC as well.

Comment: Could you link to an example?