# Visual Studio compilation omit's the code inside the.aspx files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I've noticed a strange thing in the Visual Studio 2010 Prosessional (in the ASP.NET MVC 3 project). If I have the syntax like below, the compiler doesn't checks if there is any error inside.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

<div class="author-box">
    <div class="author-box-header">
        <%: Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "", new { id = item.AuthorID }) %>
    </div>
    <div class="author-box-body">
        Books: <%: Html.DisplayFor(o => item.Books.Count) %> 
        // Here's the error, shoutld be item.Book.Count
    </div>
</div>

<% } %>
```

Only when I open that .aspx page by myself in the solution, then the compiler validates the code.

> So, how to force the compiler to automatically chcecks the syntax
>   while compilating the project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can when you compile your views. Here is [a post about that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500078/can-razor-views-be-compiled)

[Here is the tutorial on how to do it](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/), which was accepted as answer

From the community wiki post:

> after your build your solution to compile it, your will see that your
>   view will be compiled too.
>
> **NOTE** to test it, break some code on one of your view on purpose and
>   try to build. you will see that you'll get an error message

So doing that means: break a view; break the build. Which seems like what you want