# How to have Visual Studio 2012 returned compile errors on razor syntax error in "asp.net web page 2"? (Website package, not project or web app)

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2012, webmatrix, razor-2

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I wrote some Razor scripts in *.cshtml.  I'm not using MVC but "asp.net web page 2" (the term which is what Microsoft called it).  It is created as website package (not project package or web-application).

When I compile it and run the website, I ran into a razor syntax error on the website.  Upon closer inspection I noticed Visual Studio see the syntax error w/ red underline but it is allowed to compile anyway.

So, is there a flag or something I need to turn on in Visual Studio to enforce the razor errors.  Yes, I know it takes longer to compile but we do need it cuz we can't see everything at runtime and we missed some of the errors when it was deployed to production site.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5515293/34397 should work.

Comment: If `MvcBuildViews` doesn't work in this context, one of the other answers in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383192/compile-views-in-asp-net-mvc might work for 'ASP.Net web page 2'

Comment: The whole thing is created as Website in Visual Studio, not Web Application in Project.  So, no *.csproj file here.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Web Site projects are compiled on the first request. There is no Build as such. If you want that level of protection, you need to ditch Web Pages and use either Web Forms or MVC - both of which allow you to create Web Applications.

Comment: I noticed if I added "Empty Web Application" project, no "asp.net web page 2" containing razor 2 components are support from NuGet.  :-(

Comment: Web Application projects are not supported by the Web Pages framework. As I said in my answer, you need to use either MVC or Web Forms if you want a Web Application project.