# ASP.NET MVC Embedding View and VirtualPathProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, virtualpathprovider

I've developed a software based on ASP.NET MVC and want to protect my `View's Razor` content. For that I created a resource file and put them there then used `VirtualPathProvider` for handling `.cshtml` request.

problem : views using `@Html.Partial` and no request send to `GetFile` method in `VirtualPathProvider` class.

any solution ?

Comment: No solution but just curious, why you need to protect `.cshtml` ?

Comment: @CuongLe , the final project is going to run on customer's machine and view's source will be available with Notepad!

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but if you want to deter casual viewers/make views non-updatable -  maybe view precompilation would be easier path? see here for discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5515293/1123692

Comment: why not have a project that calls your hidden project as a portable area. this way all your important files are in a dll. and called from the project that has nothing.

Comment: @RichBailo , I'm actually doing that. I put my razor contents to external `dll` and load them in project , the problem is `VirtualPathProvider` can not understand `@Html.Partial` !

Comment: place the whole project in as Portable area, much easier. you can not share views between projects but you will have to write a custom virtual path provider which could be quite a lot of work. For example you may take a look at the following article which illustrates a custom provider which allows embedding Razor views into separate assemblies and reusing them across multiple MVC applications. http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/  but if the whole project is portable area you can just route to the area on run.