# MVC application is slow for every page after restart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

Additionaly to the infamous slow-start problem, which occurrs in ASP.NET application running on IIS, we experience another one.

After a fresh application start (e.g. iisreset) the first request takes some time as usual. However in the current application every other request to a page that hasn't been loaded yet takes about 10-12 second on the first hit!

After the page has loaded, all other requests to the same resource are fast again (80-130 ms usually). This is also true for first loads from other client machines, so this is not a client-caching problem.

For example:

```
Machine | Request           | Duration |
A       | GET /             | 43000 ms | (wakeup)
A       | GET /             |    90 ms |
B       | GET /             |    90 ms |
A       | GET /registration | 12000 ms |
A       | GET /registration |   110 ms |
A       | GET /registration |   110 ms |
A       | GET /registration |   110 ms |
A       | GET /foobar       | 11000 ms |
A       | GET /foobar       |    85 ms |
B       | GET /baz          | 10000 ms |
A       | GET /baz          |   100 ms |
```

The interesting thing is that this doesn't happen when we run the application on our DEV machines (debug=true, etc). Only when we publish the website (debug=false, precompile, etc) this behaviour occurrs.

All static resources are bundled and cached properly and there is not one request that may take more than 1 second really. The application pool and the website are configured to start automatically and run forver.

I would greatly appreciate any hint.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm pulling my hair out (metaphorically).

Comment: nope. best solution so far: curl all the URLs after start. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to precompile the Razor views.

You can find an example [here](https://blog.rsuter.com/precompile-asp-net-mvc-razor-views-in-release-mode-to-find-errors-at-compile-time/) although the author presents it as a way to find syntax errors in views at project compile time.

Further materials can also be found in the answers to ['Can Razor views be compiled?' question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500078/can-razor-views-be-compiled).