# How do you precompile MVC 5 Razor Views in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

hope this is an easy one. I've googled all over to find the answer to this, but have only come up with C# instructions. I can't seem to correlate/find the files that are mentioned to implement this. Any quick direction?

Comment: More searching revealed some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500078/can-razor-views-be-compiled. I'm using VS2015 and, to be honest, unless I am doing something wrong, I don't see ANY increase in speed on the first hit to each rendered page. So I wind up continuing to MANUALLY go to each page to make it faster the subsequent. Surely, there must be a better approach...?

Answer (score 0):

Publish you web app and change the settings to precompile the application.
Menu->Build->Publish XYZ->Create Profile->Select connection->Settings->File Publish Options->Precompile during publishing (Check), click on configure to configure more.

[image]

**Edit:**

In advanced precompile settings, uncheck the updatable option. Merge all output to single assembly. Check Treat as library component.

[image]

Yes I do see some improvement in the first call to website after AppPool starts. Rest all is same.

Comment: Yes - I've done that (per my comment to my original post), but as I said I still see NO speed improvement. Assuming you've used this - do you see a first-hit performance increase?

Comment: This is incorrect. The "Precompilation" settings in Visual Studio Web Application projects only apply to ASP.NET Web Forms files (`.aspx`, `.ascx`, `.asax`, `.ashx`, `.asmx`) and not to Razor files (`.cshtml`, `.vbhtml`). For that you need a separate tool like RazorGenerator (in the VS Extensions gallery).