Lost the .sln to some compiled ASPX code, how easy is it to recreate the whole page assuming I have the compiled code?
I might have an unusual question here, but I need to make an edit to an ASPX page. Specifically, this:
<asp:BoundField DataField="oldField" HeaderText="vBudget" DataFormatString="{0:C0}">
<ItemStyle BorderWidth="20px" BorderColor="Transparent" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
</asp:BoundField>

I have a DataField that I have named oldField and wanted to have it start pulling from a field called newField. So what I did was go into the ASPX page and did a CTRL+F for every instance of oldField and replaced it with newField. Unfortunately for me, it's not quite that simple. When I ran the page, I got a nullpointer exception:
Internal exception occured

Exception details:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Upon a quick search, it's because what I have is the compiled code and not the original. IF I wanted to make an update to it, I would need the original .sln or whatever in order to make changes to it.
Unfortunately, it seems to be lost and no one seems to know where it is. With that said, how hard would it be for me to recreate the same exact page with the only change I need to make to it would be to pull from newField instead of oldField? I have every piece of the compiled code which includes the MASTER file, DLLs, web.config files, JavaScipt, everything. Everything except for the .sln. I have very limited experience with developing ASPX pages.
Thank you!

If you do not have the source code then it will be very difficult. It is possible to reverse-engineer a dll somewhat (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58659068/decompile-and-reverse-engineer-a-dll-to-produce-an-asp-net-mvc-web-project). But it will probably be much  better to start over (preferably with a modern framework).

You don't necessarily need the .sln file, as it can be re-created (often with ease).
What you require is the source code files.
That aspx page might be called Customer.Aspx. There will be a corresponding Customer.aspx.cs (for c#), and for vb, it would be Customer.aspx.vb.
Hence this:

So, you need to use visual studio to modify that page, and when you re- build and re-compile the project, the correct code behind (the page class) will also be re-compiled and re-created.
In some cases, you can modify the aspx page, and not re-compile. However, things that use code behind, and things like references to controls, or changing control names? In most [! [ cases require a re-compile.
So, you have to look at your files, and it is possible that you do have the source code files. If yes then use visual studio to modify the project.
Keep in mind there is are two types of projects.
Asp.net web site
Asp.net web site "application"

Only the 2nd project type above requires a .sln file.
The first type of project is to be opened using File->open web site.
This option:

You thus then browse to the folder that contains the web site. Such projects thus don't need nor have a .sln file.
Then there is the 2nd option: Asp.net web site "application".
For these projects, then you use file->open project.
So, check the folder with the .aspx pages. If you have the .cs (or .vb) pages (the code behind), then you are in great shape.
In the case of an "application"? Then during deploy, the site is compiled, and source code files are stripped out at deploy time. And only "applications" have a. designer file.
I should also point out that when using the "web site" option, then IIS (the web server) does the code compile, and source code is required to be deployed along with the .aspx pages.
For the "application" option then as noted, then the designer and code behind files are not placed on the server, and Visual Studio does the code compile BEFORE the publish option is used.
So, check if you have the code behind files, and if you do, and you don't see "designer" files, then you have a web site, but you have all of the source code, and thus you can make such changes, but you need the code behind files for either of the above choices.
