# MvcBuildViews doesn't do anything

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using the standard instructions to compile views at design time, by adding this to my vbproj file:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.  I added a compilation error to a vbhtml file and compiled the app.  **If the file is open in Visual Studio**, I get the compilation error whether `MvcBuildViews` is true or false.  If the file is closed, I don't get the error, even on full build, even when `MvcBuildViews` is true.

This is VS2012, and I've added the `MvcBuildViews` entry to every single PropertyGroup in my project file, but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**: I just upgraded to VS2013 and I still have the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVCBuildViews not working correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725387/mvcbuildviews-not-working-correctly)

Comment: @MikeCheel: No, I read that post, but I am not getting the same error reported in that post (in fact, I'm not getting any error).

Comment: Did you try removing the obj\debug and such as in that article? Are you able to show your proj file?

Comment: I did delete `obj`, yes. I tried a number of measures from the article, but I think most of them are focused on deleting bogus web.config files, to get rid of the error he was having, but I don't get that error.

Comment: I ws able to reproduce the no warning\ no error like you have. You also need to add the correct post build stuff. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/542944/426422 I got it working when I follow the guys steps.

Comment: When I added that, the post build threw a bunch of errors that don't actually happen in the IDE, and I *still* don't get an error for the offending razor view.

Comment: What I did to get mine working (I did it in 2013 express, mvc 5) was first unload the project and then edit it. I then put my MvcBuildViews property in the section for my debug \ any cpu property group. Then I copied that AfterBuild blurb right after the commented out version at the bottom of the file. Voila.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50827/discussion-between-joshua-frank-and-mike-cheel)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I gave up to MvcBuildViews and did a job using RazorGenerator

https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator

1. Install it from nuget
2. Install an **Razor Generator** extension in your Visual Studio. (Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online Tab -> Search For **Razor Generator** and install
3. Right Click your view -> Click Properties -> Make sure **Custom Tool** says **RazorGenerator**

[image]

Comment: This is clever. Having to set the Custom Tool on every single view seems tedious though. Any way to automate that or maybe run a job outside of the IDE to do this compilation?

Comment: When I usually start project like this, I do it once and then just copy paste views, (it's kinda habit) so don't need to set Properties manually. Unfortunately couldn't find better way to compile views