# @Html.Partial - Razor: I get Error Message, but it still works

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting the `"System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for Partial and no extension method Partial accepting a first argument of type System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper could be found"` error message when using `@Html.Partial`. BUT, it still works as expected, and my partial shows up. I want to get rid of the error however. Here is my html, if it helps :-

```
<div id="reference">
@Html.Partial("Reference/_PermissionType")
@Html.Partial("Reference/_ProtocolType")
@Html.Partial("Reference/_ResponseType")
@Html.Partial("Reference/_SystemType")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy `web.config` file from `Views folder` and put it in your `Reference folder` from where your partial views are referenced.

Comment: Tried it, but got same error. Since my Web.config file is in the Views folder, shouldn't it be picked up by all cshtml files that are in folders in Views? And why would everything still work, even though I am getting errors?

Comment: @Scott...strange how this is possible...you are getting errors on runtime or compile time????

Comment: If I unload the project and set MvcBuildViews to true in the .csproj file, I get compile errors, but the app still runs fine. Yes, very strange.

Comment: just read this link....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725387/mvcbuildviews-not-working-correctly/4732019#4732019