# Knockout.js binding gets broken when property of ViewModel renamed

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

This is the first time I'm asking a question here, so please be tolerant :)

In an MVC web application powered up by knockout.js, I have, for clear example:

1. Simple ViewModel class in C#:

   ```
   public class RetailCustomer
   {
       public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Simple binding in knockout.js on MVC view:

   ```
   function CustomerCtxViewModel() {
       var self = this;
       self.FirstName = ko.observable('');
       self.LastName = ko.observable('');
       self.BirthDate = ko.observable('');
       $.getJSON("/api/RetailContext", function (data) {
           self.FirstName(data.FirstName);
           self.LastName(data.LastName);
           self.BirthDate(data.BirthDate);
       }
   }
   ```

Then I renamed the property `BirthDate` in `RetailCustomer` class to `Birthdate`, because Code Analysis told me so... and the binding doesn't work anymore of course, and the worst thing is I find it out only during runtime.

**QUESTION**: Are there any tools, techniques that would warn me early enough, during compile time or automated builds maybe, so that I can see my mistake before the app is running?

Comment: IMO No . As html is rendered run-time so usually we get to see the error when app runs 
.

Comment: If you want to not get downvoted, you should learn what is and is not on topic.  Asking for tool recommendations is definitely not on topic.  Read the "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" section in the [tour].  Other than that, you'll do fine.

Comment: @will, thanks for feedback. I rather meant to find out whatever solution could be useful here, be it a coding technique or software development tool, and both of those are clearly stated on the tour page as topics I **should** ask about ;)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/t54TL.png

Comment: And "Software development tools" just 2 lines above

Answer (score 1):

**super cool** is correct: binding happens at runtime and the viewmodel is a dynamic object, so there is no practical way to ensure that the viewmodel and required bindings match up at compile/build time.

*In principle*, if you were using TypeScript, a build process could analyze the HTML and infer an Interface from it, which could then be applied to your viewmodel, but even that would be just the general case of `applyBindings` where it applies to the whole HTML doc. `applyBindings` can be used on individual HTML elements. It would be a very complicated system and nothing like it has been attempted as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

For this cases, you can use the @Html.NameFor helper, in case your data object (the JSON) is of the same type as the Model on your .cshtml file. If you want to validate syntax on compile time, you can edit the csproj and define **MvcBuildViews** to true. That way, you will know on compile time when Razor will fail. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725387/mvcbuildviews-not-working-correctly) if you have problems with compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it, but [T4TS](https://github.com/cskeppstedt/t4ts) can generate a TypeScript interface definition from C# classes.

C#:

```
[TypeScriptInterface]
public class RetailCustomer
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON("/api/RetailContext", function (data: T4TS.RetailCustomer) {
    self.FirstName(data.FirstName);
    self.LastName(data.LastName);
    self.BirthDate(data.BirthDate);
}
```

I also found [TypeLITE](http://type.litesolutions.net/) which does much the same.