# How to exclude path from precompilation for AspNetCompiler in csproj

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, aspnet-compiler

example on command line that i use to exclude `Admin` path with `-x`

`C:\Users\Test>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /Application.Web -p D:\Application.Web -x /Application.Web/Admin`

after run this result is fine. But when i translate to `csproj` scripts.

from lib https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx

It does not parameter to exclude path from precompilation.

Currently command on csproj file

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'"> 
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="Application.Web" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to call the `aspnet_compiler.exe` directly as per this blogpost https://matthewrwilton.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/excluding-node_modules-folder-from-asp-net-compilation/
because the `AspNetCompiler` msbuild task doesn't have a property for exclusions.

Good thing is that you can call it with multiple exclusions, like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <exclusion1>some/path</exclusion1>
    <exclusion2>another/path</exclusion2>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <Exec Command="$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath)aspnet_compiler.exe -v temp -p $(WebProjectOutputDir) -x $(exclusion1) -x $(exclusion2)"/>
</Target>
```

Just remember to use the -x parameter once per exclusion.

Comment: @Aixaz is this not the answer you were looking for?

Comment: +1 used this way to invoke acpnet compiler to compile cshtml files in an MVC project that included an angular page. By default it was trying to compile the node-modules folder with a c++ compiler which was unable to find in the system.

Comment: @Ilias.P Glad you found it useful. I had the same problem, and wanted to share the solution.