# Build error in visual studio 2019 - It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

When I build my application in visual studio, I am getting below error:

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
C:\Users\application\Web.Config 195

However, at line 195 of web.config, I don't have anything for allowDefinition section. I guess this is because there may be another web.config in system which is getting inherited here. I tried to search in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config but nothing is mentioned for allowDefinition attribute.

I tried old web.config but still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried going to the folder and deleted all the obj and bin folders.

Or click `Convert to Application` in IIS Manager

Also try deleting the `web.config`, try creating a new one.

Finally check [`<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725387/mvcbuildviews-not-working-correctly)